# Convert image stored on remote folder to base64 in web app

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In my web app i need to convert images on catalog to string
Catalogue are created in a listview with .NET Framework 4 using webform

```
Protected Sub ProductsLv_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ProductsLv.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
            Dim dataRow = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
            Dim path = Replace("~/Products/Immagine.ashx?FileName=" & dataRow("ImageName"), "\\machine\Foto\", "")
            path = "http://" & Me.Request.Url.Host & ResolveUrl(path)
            Dim sBase64 As String = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"
            Using w As New System.Net.WebClient()
                Dim buffer As Byte() = w.DownloadData(path)
                sBase64 &= Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)
            End Using
            DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("myIMG"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).ImageUrl = sBase64
    End If
End Sub
```

Code above seems works well because i found string on image source of html produced by server response
but images are not visible

What mistake i making?

The value of sBase64 is
data:image/jpeg;base64,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

Comment: Why not set the `ImageUrl` property to the `path` variable, and skip the base64 conversion completely?

Answer (score 0):

ImageUrl needs a relative or absolute path. So try setting “src” attribute instead, as follows.

```
DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("myIMG"), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image).Attributes("src") = sBase64
```

Comment: Can you add in your original question the Base64  final output of sBase64 variable?

Comment: i added the output

Comment: Full result please